# How to handle incoming mails?

Tags: php, email, handle, exim

We are developing a Client Support System.
So we need to handle every mail once we get it.
How to configure Exim? When the mail is received. It has to be handle (in php). For example it has to be inserted in DB.

Comment: Anton, please post what have you tried in your next questions; The community is here to help, but you must also show what you tryed; You will see soon that people will ask: What have you tryed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure exim to pipe the mail to a php script.

Here is a tutorial on how to achieve this: http://www.activecampaign.com/support/tt/kb/article/help-desk/version-25x-26x/setting-up-supporttrio/setting-up-your-server-to-forward-email-to-the-pipe-script

The php script you "pipe" the mail to will receive the emails content via `stdin`, which enables you to insert it into the db.

Comment: I don't have any idea why I didn't find this. Thanks alot.

Comment: It helps to know what you are looking for. You are welcome. :)

Comment: Anton, please post what have you tried in your next questions; The community is here to help, but you must also show what you tryed; You will see soon that people will ask: What have you tryed?